# Background-image do not change

Tags: html, css

```html
<style>
    .aboutmovie 
        {
            background-image: url("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1000/rjUl3pd1LHVOVfG4IGcyA1cId5l.jpg");
 }
</style>

<div class="aboutmovie"> 
    <h1>Helloo</h1>
</div>


<style>
    .aboutmovie 
        {
            background-image: url("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1000/5pAGnkFYSsFJ99ZxDIYnhQbQFXs.jpg");
 }
</style>

<div class="aboutmovie"> 
    <h1>Helloo</h1>
</div>
```

I am using PHP to do this. So, i cannot put different style for all div's etc..

What is the problem in this code? Why the background-image do not change? The code is self-explanatory, i guess.

Comment: The second `.aboutmovie { ... }` definition overrides the first. It doesn't matter where in the document you add the style tags. All `.aboutmovie` elements will use the last styles defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can change the class of each div, and if you using PHP, it makes it even easier.

Do this:

Since you are fetching results from MySQL, your code should be something like this:

```
$aboutmovienumber = 0;

foreach ($xyz as $row)
{
$aboutmovienumber++;

echo'
<style>
.aboutmovie'.$aboouutmovienumber.' {
your CSS code here
}
</style>


<div class="aboutmovie'.$aboouutmovienumber.'">hello</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use two `style` blocks, that won't work the way you imagine (i.e. for the same class).

You can use the `:nth-of-type(1)` pseudo class on the `.aboutmovie` class as demonstrated below

```html
<style type="text/css">
  .aboutmovie:nth-of-type(1) {
    background-image: url("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1000/rjUl3pd1LHVOVfG4IGcyA1cId5l.jpg");
  }
  
  .aboutmovie:nth-of-type(2) {
    background-image: url("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1000/5pAGnkFYSsFJ99ZxDIYnhQbQFXs.jpg");
  }
</style>

<div class="aboutmovie">
  <h1>Helloo</h1>
</div>

<div class="aboutmovie">
  <h1>Helloo</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I cannot use PHP in CSS file bro. That is the problem. I am fetching background-images from Mysql.

Comment: Well, so write it into a `<style>` tag in the HTML page - I'll edit my answer accordingly

Comment: Can you tell me, why this fiddle is not working? https://jsfiddle.net/w9zjj1k1/1/

I am sorry, but my code got other div's also. If i remove `<div class="xyz">zdas</div>` , then it works

Comment: It's because you also inserted other DIVs in between, which you hadn't in the code of your original question. `nth-of-type` relates to the DIV, not only to the class. I would use additional classes for your ".aboutmovie" elements like here: https://jsfiddle.net/y1k5ncL2/

Answer (score 1):

In your styles, your second `background-image` property override the first one because you specify them on the same class `aboutmovie`.

You can check CSS cascading (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Cascade).

If you want another background image on the second div, you may use another class.

Answer (score 0):

All CSS snippets in the one document get interpreted together, meaning that the second time you set .aboutmovie background-image will override the first, before the HTML page is built and displayed.

It's the same as writing

```
<style>
.class {background-image: url('img_1.png')}
.class {background-image: url('img_2.png')}
</style>
```

Class will have the first background set, and then overridden with the second image.

You'd need to find a way to use in-line CSS, or use different **class**, or **id** names.

Like so

```
<style>
    #about1 {
        background-image: url("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1000/rjUl3pd1LHVOVfG4IGcyA1cId5l.jpg");
    }
</style>

    <div id="about1">   
    <h1>Helloo</h1>
    </div>

<style>
    #about2 {
        background-image: url("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1000/5pAGnkFYSsFJ99ZxDIYnhQbQFXs.jpg");
    }
</style>

    <div id="about2">   
    <h1>Helloo</h1>
    </div>
```